# The findOneAndRemove and findOneAndUpdate don't work as intended

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to make a "like" toggle as in Facebook.

My code works fine when there is no previous "like".

and also deletes find when there is only one "like".

but it starts to become problem when there are many likes.

as I like to different posts,

[image]

it adds on with correct reference

[image]

I added one more

[image]

Now this is the problem - I actually pressed the toggle button for the third one, but the result is different. The topmost one got deleted.

My model made of Mongoose Schemas are following:

```
var postSchema  = new Schema({
    title: {type:String},
    content: {type:String},
    likeId:[{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Like'}],
    user:{type:Schema.ObjectId},
    commentId:[{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Comment'}],
    created:{type:Date, default:Date.now}
});

var likeSchema  = new Schema({
    user: Schema.ObjectId,
    postId: {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Post'},
    created:{type:Date, default:Date.now}
});
```

there are no middlewares.

This is controller part of my app:

```
exports.postLikes = function(req,res){
    var like = new Like({
        postId: req.params.postId,
        user: req.user._id
    });
    Like.find()
    // find like "to the post" and "by the user"
    .and([
        {user:req.user._id},
        {postId:req.params.postId}
    ]) 
    //and then execute the following
    .exec(function(err, result){
        //if it exists, return "result"
        if(result.length > 0){ 
            //remove the result by result.id
            Like.findOneAndRemove(result[0]._id, function(err){ 
                //pull off the reference from likeId array in Post
                Post.findOneAndUpdate({'_id':req.params.postId}, {$pull:{'likeId':result[0]._id}}, function(err){ 
                    if(err){res.send(err);} 
                    res.json({status:'deleted'});
                });
            });
        }
        else{
            like.save(function(err){
                if(err){res.send(err);}
                Post.findById(req.params.postId, function(err,post){
                    if(err) return res.send(err);
                    post.likeId.push(like);
                    post.save(function(err){
                        if(err) return res.send(err);
                        res.json({status:'done'});
                    });
                });
            });         
        };
    });
};
```

Excuse my messy code.

I've been trying to get this to work for two days straight, couldn't find the way. HELP ME :(

---

Data I used are:

"LIKE" JSON OBJECT ARRAY

(data for likes are already removed, so I made them again)

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5560de9f9c93fb28161a7375"),
  "postId" : ObjectId("5560d511cae220180c37f9d3"),
  "user" : ObjectId("5560daf3a09140800bb70a41"),
  "created" : ISODate("2015-05-23T20:10:07.002Z"),
  "__v" : 0
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5560e7c98d6e3fbc15999daa"),
  "postId" : ObjectId("5560d514cae220180c37f9d4"),
  "user" : ObjectId("5560daf3a09140800bb70a41"),
  "created" : ISODate("2015-05-23T20:49:13.867Z"),
  "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5560e7d78d6e3fbc15999dab"),
  "postId" : ObjectId("5560d515cae220180c37f9d5"),
  "user" : ObjectId("5560daf3a09140800bb70a41"),
  "created" : ISODate("2015-05-23T20:49:27.65Z"),
  "__v" : 0
}
```

"POST" JSON OBJECT ARRAY

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5560d511cae220180c37f9d3"),
  "title" : "titleteset",
  "content" : "contentetest",
  "user" : ObjectId("555d71825b6be608081553f1"),
  "created" : ISODate("2015-05-23T19:29:21.732Z"),
  "commentId" : [],
  "likeId" : [ObjectId("5560d542cae220180c37f9dd"), ObjectId("5560d7799dbb4fe8114fa90c"), ObjectId("5560d8c1194d94f80aa4f230"), ObjectId("5560dba8a09140800bb70a47")],
  "__v" : 19
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5560d514cae220180c37f9d4"),
  "title" : "titleteset",
  "content" : "contentetest",
  "user" : ObjectId("555d71825b6be608081553f1"),
  "created" : ISODate("2015-05-23T19:29:24.027Z"),
  "commentId" : [],
  "likeId" : [ObjectId("5560d554cae220180c37f9de"), ObjectId("5560de899c93fb28161a7374"), ObjectId("5560e7c98d6e3fbc15999daa")],
  "__v" : 4
}

/* 2 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5560d515cae220180c37f9d5"),
  "title" : "titleteset",
  "content" : "contentetest",
  "user" : ObjectId("555d71825b6be608081553f1"),
  "created" : ISODate("2015-05-23T19:29:25.761Z"),
  "commentId" : [],
  "likeId" : [ObjectId("5560db7ea09140800bb70a46"), ObjectId("5560e7d78d6e3fbc15999dab")],
  "__v" : 4
}
```

---

adding on:

I refactored my code as @Andrew Layers suggested,

I found:

```
{ _id: 5560ef48a082c31c0a29062f,
  postId: 5560d511cae220180c37f9d3,
  user: 5560daf3a09140800bb70a41,
  __v: 0,
  created: Sun May 24 2015 06:21:12 GMT+0900 (Korea Standard Time) }
POST /api/posts/5560d511cae220180c37f9d3/likes 200 26.621 ms - 179
{ _id: 5560ef48a082c31c0a29062f,
  postId: 5560d511cae220180c37f9d3,
  user: 5560daf3a09140800bb70a41,
  __v: 0,
  created: Sun May 24 2015 06:21:12 GMT+0900 (Korea Standard Time) }
POST /api/posts/5560d511cae220180c37f9d3/likes 200 14.333 ms - 179
{ _id: 5560ef48a082c31c0a29062f,
  postId: 5560d511cae220180c37f9d3,
  user: 5560daf3a09140800bb70a41,
  __v: 0,
  created: Sun May 24 2015 06:21:12 GMT+0900 (Korea Standard Time) }
POST /api/posts/5560d511cae220180c37f9d3/likes 200 20.195 ms - 179
```

I get the exactly same result variable, but findOneAndRemove removes other items not specified by result variable.

The problem seems to be from logic in removing and pulling off reference, still don't know the cause.

Comment: @chridam Did you mean the sample data I added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem in querying findOneAndRemove and putting only id to find it. *facepalm*

Using findByIdAndRemove simply solved the problem.

So My fixed code is now:

```
exports.postLikes = function(req,res){
    var like = new Like({
        postId: req.params.postId,
        user: req.user._id
    });
    Like.findOne({
        user:req.user._id,
        postId:req.params.postId
    }).exec(function(err, result){
        //if it exists, return "result"
        if(result) { 
            console.log(result);
            //remove the result by result.id
            Like.findByIdAndRemove(result._id, function(err){ 
                //pull off the reference from likeId array in Post
                Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.postId, {$pull:{'likeId':result._id}}, function(err){ 
                    if(err){res.send(err);} 
                    res.json({status:'deleted', result:result});
                });
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log(result);
            like.save(function(err){
                if(err){res.send(err);}
                Post.findById(req.params.postId, function(err,post){
                    if(err) return res.send(err);
                    post.likeId.push(like);
                    post.save(function(err, foo){
                        if(err) return res.send(err);
                        res.json({status:'done', result:foo});
                    });
                });
            });         
        };
    });
};
```

It works beautifully and now i can get to sleep, thank you all for helping me, especially for @Andrew Lavers who suggested better code.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that your `Like.find` query is returning more than one document, and the `findOneAndRemove` code is simply removing the first one in the list rather than the specific one you want.

You could test this by logging `result.length` to see if this is the case.

In any case, there's no reason to create a `Like` object in order to run your query. The `and()` is also not necessary. Instead, you could just use `findOne` like this:

```
Like.findOne({
    user:req.user._id,
    postId:req.params.postId
}).exec(function(err, result){
    //if it exists, return "result"
    if(result) { 
        //remove the result by result.id
        Like.findOneAndRemove(result._id, function(err){ 
            //pull off the reference from likeId array in Post
            Post.findOneAndUpdate({'_id':req.params.postId}, {$pull:{'likeId':result._id}}, function(err){ 
                if(err){res.send(err);} 
                res.json({status:'deleted'});
            });
        });
    } else {
        //...        
    }
});
```

If the document doesn't exist, `result` will be `null` and your else block will execute.

Comment: I followed your code. The result._id returns exactly same id pointing my Post, but deletes other likes. It is little strange that It seems to work for for a few toggles... and then it continues to delete every likes I have, including likes from other users.